# Symfony2 Sensio GeneratorBundle : Add a linebreak in skeleton

Tags: php, symfony, code-generation, newline

I created my own GeneratorBundle (based on the SensioGeneratorBundle) to create a FormType class file based on an Entity. It generates the file like it should, but the problem is that inside the for-loop to generate the fields of the entity, it puts all the code on the same line. I would like to have the generated code inside the for-loop to be on a new line for each field. I tried adding `\n` or `< br/>` but that didn't work.

The command :

```
php app/console kuma:generate:adminlist Bundle:Entity
```

Command class :

```
    class GenerateAdminListCommand extends GenerateDoctrineCommand
    {   
         
        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {
            
            $entity = $input->getOption('entity');
            list($bundle, $entity) = $this->parseShortcutNotation($entity);

            $entityClass = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityNamespace($bundle) . '\\' . $entity;
            $metadata = $this->getEntityMetadata($entityClass);
            
            $admintypeGenerator = $this->getAdminListTypeGenerator();
            $admintypeGenerator->generate($bundle, $entity, $metadata[0]);
```

My Generator class :

```
    
    class AdminListTypeGenerator extends \Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Generator\Generator
    {
        
        public function generate($bundle, $entity, $metadata)
        {
            
            $parameters = array('namespace' => $bundle->getNamespace(), 'bundle' => $bundle, 'entity_class' => $entityClass, 'fields' => $this->getFieldsFromMetadata($metadata));

            $this->renderFile($this->skeletonDir, 'EntityAdminListType.php', $dirPath . '/' . $entity . 'AdminListType.php', $parameters);
        }
```

extends the following class :

```
class Generator
{
    protected function render($skeletonDir, $template, $parameters)
    {
        $twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($skeletonDir), array(
            'debug'            => true,
            'cache'            => false,
            'strict_variables' => true,
            'autoescape'       => false,
        ));

        return $twig->render($template, $parameters);
    }

    protected function renderFile($skeletonDir, $template, $target, $parameters)
    {
        if (!is_dir(dirname($target))) {
            mkdir(dirname($target), 0777, true);
        }

        return file_put_contents($target, $this->render($skeletonDir, $template, $parameters));
    }
}
```

The fields are extracted from the metadata :

```
    public static function getFieldsFromMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $fields = (array) $metadata->fieldNames;

        // Remove the primary key field if it's not managed manually
        if (!$metadata->isIdentifierNatural()) {
            $fields = array_diff($fields, $metadata->identifier);
        }

        foreach ($metadata->associationMappings as $fieldName => $relation) {
            if ($relation['type'] !== ClassMetadata::ONE_TO_MANY) {
                $fields[] = $fieldName;
            }
        }

        return $fields;
    }
```

In my skeleton file :

```
    
        public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) 
        {
            {%- for field in fields %}
                $builder->add('{{ field }}');
            {%- endfor %}
        }
```

And this is how the buildForm() method looks when generated based on the skeleton above :

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) 
    {   $builder->add('ip');    $builder->add('timestamp'); $builder->add('firstname'); $builder->add('lastname');  }
```

So I want `$builder->add('{{ field }}');` to create a new line in every new iteration. The result should look like this :

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) 
    {           
        $builder->add('ip');
        $builder->add('timestamp');
        $builder->add('firstname');
        $builder->add('lastname');          
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems I found the solution with help of a colleague.

The problem was the "-" inside the twig syntax :

```
{%- for field in fields %}
```

That minus means it has to be put on one line. Removing the minus did the trick.

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) 
    {
        {% for field in fields %}
        $builder->add('{{ field }}');
        {% endfor %}
    }
```

Now it renders :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) 
    {
                $builder->add('ip');
                $builder->add('timestamp');
                $builder->add('firstname');
                $builder->add('lastname');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
 $builder->add('ip') .'<br/>'. $builder->add('timestamp');
```

Comment: @umai-iqbal Ok, I edited my skeleton file to this : 
<pre><code>
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) 
    {
     {%- for field in fields %}
   $builder->add('{{ field }}');.'<br/>'
        {%- endfor %}
    }
</code></pre>

This gave the following generated code (on one line) :
<code>
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) 
    { $builder->add('ip');.'<br/>'  $builder->add('timestamp');.'<br/>' $builder->add('firstname');.'<br/>' }
</code>

The problem is the rendered doesn't see the br or \n as a linebreak

Comment: Are your fields coming from database ?

Comment: No, they're extracted from the MetaData of the class using the SensioGeneratorBundle's method "getEntityMetadata" in class "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineCommand". I'll try editing my question to add this part of the code

Comment: Edited my question, I hope this gives a better view of what's happening

Comment: Your fields are coming in a single dimension array try adding a break at the end of each entry (which I am not sure will work or not) Try to convert your array to two dimension array and then adding each index of the 2 dimension array...

Comment: The entry is just the field name, that field name is being parsed by {{ field }} inside "$builder->add('{{ field }}');". I tried adding a break behind that line of code, but it doesn't get recognised by the renderer/generator. I'll add the generator code to the question.

Comment: By the way add will automatically add the line break if you can see the your filds in a view

Comment: Why don't you create the field name inside the form builder ? I mean the Form class